# Getting missing positional parameter errors when using scipy odeint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am attempting to code a basic gravitational 2 body problem (2 bodies of equal mass), by using scipy odeint to solve the differential equations. Code below

```
#N Body test case

#%%

#import modules

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

#%%

#define constants

G=6.67e-11
AU=1.496e11
m1= m2=1.989e30

def twobody(x1, y1, vx1, vy1, x2, y2, vx2, vy2):
    
    rx=x1-x2
    ry=y1-y2
    r=np.sqrt(rx**2+ry**2)
    
    f=[vx1, vy1, vx2, vy2, G*m2*rx/r**3, G*m2*ry/r**3, G*m1*rx/r**3, G*m2*ry/r**3]
    
    return f

t=np.linspace(0, 1.577e8, 2000)

initial=[-0.5*AU, -0.5*AU, 0,0,0,0,-15000, 15000]

twobodysol=odeint(twobody, initial, t, args=(m1, m2))
```

I keep getting an error:

```
twobody() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'x2', 'y2', 'vx2', and 'vy2'
```

Can anyone help with what I've done wrong here?
Many thanks

Comment: According to `odeint` docs, `twobody` is supposed to accept `y, t, ...`.  `y` is the `initial` array (8 elements), `t` is time, and `...` is the `args`, 2 terms, `m1,m2`.  Reread the `odeint` docs carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `odeint` is old, [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) recommends using `solve_ivp()`. Your function should look something like func(y, t, ...) where y is the initial condition array, and t is an array containing time points to calculate. All the other parameters you have to provide yourself through the `args` parameter of `odeint()`. 
With what you've supplied to `odeint` your function looks like this when it is called :
`twobody(initial, t, m1, m2)`. 
Whereas you want it to look like this :

`twobody(x1, y1, vx1, vy1, x2, y2, vx2, vy2)`.

 I recommend you look into [`solve_ivp()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp).

Comment: though with `solve_ivp` he still needs to accept `twobody( t, initial, m1, m2)`

Comment: FYI: I recommend putting the `t` parameter first, and use the option `tfirst=True` in `odeint`.  Then you can use the same function with `odeint` and `solve_ivp` .